# how to show no data message in google bar chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google bar chart for my project, it is working correctly with data, but if no data exists, the bar chart is showing with empty horizontal lines. How to show no data message as in google pie chart, if there is no data exists?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `DataTable#getNumberOfRows` method.  If you have `0` rows, then fire a "no data" message: `if (data.getNumberOfRows() == 0) {/* fire "no data" message */}`.